# How do I connect the two cables entering a switch box for a light?

Tags: switch

I removed the original light fixture from the side wall which was not connected to a light switch but had a button that turned the light on and off on the fixture itself. I took the original wire in the wall and extended it further down the wall where I had made a new box for a light switch. From that new box I took a second cable and wired up the wall over the ceiling into a brand new light fixture. Now I have two separate cables at the swtich box to connect into a single light swtich. Since the single light switch has only two screws, how do I connect the double white and black cables to it?

Comment: Welcome, Jake. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you with regard to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  in the switch box, the blacks go to the switch terminals (not the green one - that's for the bare ground) and the whites are spliced together with a wire nut or other connector.

Comment: So to confirm, each black go on each screw and the whites are spliced into the nut?

Comment: To be perfectly clear - the whites do not touch the switch;  they are just spliced to each other with a wire nut.

Answer (score 2):

#### Switch Loop

The other answers tell you what to do, but they don't really *explain* it. So I'll try:

- Originally you had hot (black) and neutral (white) going from the fuse/circuit breaker panel to the fixture.
- Now you have TWO cables:

  - hot (black) and neutral (white) going from the panel to the switch
  - black and white going from the switch to the fixture.
- What you actually **need** are:

  - hot from the panel to the switch
  - switched hot from the switch to the fixture
  - neutral from the fixture to the panel

Here is what you do:

- *hot* (black) from panel to switch - if the switch has a screw labeled "line", connect it to that screw.
- *switched hot* from switch to fixture - use the black wire currently attached to the fixture - connect it to the switch. If the switch has a screw labeled "load", connect it to that screw. As noted by Harper, marking both ends of this wire in red (or some other color that isn't black, white or green) is a good idea and will make things easier for any trouble-shooting by you or a future owner.
- *neutral* from switch to fixture - use the white wires and connect them together with a wire nut in the switch box. **Do not connect them to the switch**.

The *switched hot* does not need to be black. But it often is out of convenience, and that's OK.

The *neutral* is not used by an ordinary switch. However, if you ever install a dimmer or a smart switch then you will probably need the neutral, and then you can pigtail off of the two neutrals that are connected together.

Of course, grounds should be connected as appropriate - the specifics of that will depend on the type of cables, switch, fixture, etc. But basically all grounds go together (but should not be connected to any hot, switched hot or neutral wires).

Comment: I prefer to mark switched-hot wires red, to denote their different function.

Answer (score 0):

Try a pigtail. I have attached a picture. Ignore the receptacle and pretend it's a light fixture.
[image]

Good luck

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  He's not wiring a receptacle or smart switch and I don't see call for a pigtail here.  Well, for the ground, of course, so there's that.